# AndroidManifest.xml file error

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-manifest

I am trying to generate apk of my application 'ChristmasTree' using Android Studio. I got issues with the AndroidManifest file.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.christmastree"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:label="@string/ChristmasTree"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/ChristmasTree"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" 
  />
  </application>

</manifest>
```

I got this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in your string.xml file in resource->values-->Strings.xml folder add this lines.

```
    <string name="ChristmasTree">ChristmasTree</string>
```

and add in resource--> drawable folder add and icon for your app and name it

> ic_launcher.

and add in resource--> value--> Style.xml file

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I've made changes but still have the same issue

Comment: sorry there was a mistake in my code at this line `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"` . So where do i make a change?

Comment: add an icon to drawable folder for your app and write 
        android:icon="@drawable/your_logo_name"

Comment: Then add a mipmap folder in resource folder and add your logo

Comment: Then try:
1. clean your project
2. Rebuilt your project it will work.

Comment: How to clean my project? Can you tell me the steps. I am using android-studio version 2.3

Comment: Goto toolbar --> there is an option built --> click there --> you will get the option clean project ..first do that then...after it gets complete ... goto the same place and click built project.